# Long Poll in restFb How can i implement this

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I am working with Vk client and facebook client 
currently i have implemented a vk long poll

```
public VkService longPoll() throws Exception {
        LongpollParams longpollParams = vk.
            messages().
            getLongPollServer(userActor).
            execute();
        // Unfortunately, VK Java SDK doesn't specifies protocol that's
        // suitable for Long Poll server. So we have to do it by hand.
        String fullUrlToServer = "https://" + longpollParams.getServer();
        vk.longPoll().
            getEvents(
                fullUrlToServer,
                longpollParams.getKey(),
                longpollParams.getTs()).
            waitTime(LONG_POLL_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS).
            executeAsString();
        return this;
    }
```

But i have searched but could not find a long poll for facebook or its equivalent , any suggestions?

Comment: “Long poll” for what exactly …?

Comment: long poll for getting messages at a particular time interval

Comment: What “messages” …?

Comment: I am trying to use restfb to get unread messages constantly at a particular time interval  eg every five seconds try to get unread mesages

Comment: Again, _what messages_? Are you talking about private messages users send to a page, or … what? Anyway, with the Facebook API, the way to go would not be polling in the first place, but webhooks. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

Comment: I will post my code so you see , Actually what i want is, to get a log of all messages sent to me , thats sent to a user

Comment: Messages send to a _user profile_ are not accessible via the Facebook Graph API in the first place.

Comment: i created a dummy facebook account and i want to use rest fb to see a log of messages sent to me, my dummy account is named bob , so if a user  send a mesage to bob i should see this in my log when running my app

Comment: Not possible, there is no API access to user inboxes.

Comment: so how can i access them , or its not possible ? i acheived this for Vk app

Comment: It is not possible.